# Value Sets miss an AP

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, contest-math

> For any polynomial $p\in \Bbb Z[X]$,the set $\{p(n) : n \in Z\}$ is called the value set of p.

Problem:- Let $p \in Z[X]$ be such that deg $p > 1.$ Then there exists an infinite arithmetic sequence none of who terms can be expressed as $p(x)$ for some $x \in Z.$

Progress:-

For this problem, I first took example which was $P(x)=x^2-1$ then we get the value set as $\{0,3,4,15,24,\dots\}.$ Since, $x^2-1\equiv -1,0\mod 4.$ So clearly the AP $~~2,6,10,\dots $ never come.

I assumed the contrary. Hence for any $n,d$ there will exist a $x$ such that $P(x)\equiv n \mod d.$  If there doesn't then we can select the AP $n, n+d,n+2d,\dots$

Now we know that when $p \in \Bbb[X]$, and $m\equiv n\mod d \implies P(m)\equiv P(n)\mod d.$ (*)

So, we can say that $p(n), p(n+1),\dots, p(n+d-1)$ forms a complete residue set, because if it doesn't  then by PHP, there will be an $y \in {1,2,\dots d}$ not being a residue in $p(x),$ when $n\le x\le n+d-1.$

Now, take any $d$ consecutive numbers,say $l,l+1,\dots ,l+d-1,$ by (*), residues mod $d$ of $\{P(l),\dots,P(l+d+1)\}=\{p(n), p(n+1),\dots, p(n+d-1)\}.$

This is what I have got till now.

Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an answer but a note: Szemerédi's theorem can be used quite easily to show that there are arithmetic progressions of any (finite) length missing the value sets by noting that the complement of the value set has positive upper density.

Comment: @Slugger That's well beyond high school level. I would try for $p\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[X]$ with $n$ prim. Here we could use injective = surjective.

Comment: @TomTom314 You are right, I missed that requirement

Answer (score 1):

**Short outline of a proof.**

Choose $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p(x)\equiv p(y) \mod n$. (<- This requires a detailed argument.) Then the map
$$\overline p:\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, \overline x\mapsto \overline{p(x)}$$
is not injective. Because its a map on a finite set we have $\overline p$ injective $\iff \overline p$ surjective. From here we can construct an arithmetic sequence that doesn't met $p(x)$.

Comment: I understood fully, but I don't follow how subjectivity helps?

Comment: If $\overline p$ is not surjective we have a $\overline k$ with $\overline{p(x)}\neq \overline k \forall x$. What is $\overline k$?

Comment: find a d greater than one that also make some consecutive terms modulo same. You can just pick an large enough consecutive term as d straightly then this two terms modulo d same. p.s. this is a proof from a contest book